# Explorer in Windows 7 locks up when dragging items from one window to another. How can this be rectified

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Note, this only happens when the items are dragged across the folder pane on the left hand side, so it can be worked around by taking a circuitous route with the mouse pointer. However, I would like a fix that allows the direct route across the folder pane.

I have seen this on more than one Windows 7 installation, but all the ones I have tried are attached to a domain and haved mapped drives. I do not know if the issue is caused by this or something else. If anyone without a domain and/or mapped drives can confirm whether they have the issue it would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. I have not seen this on my domain with Windows 7. Can you [edit] your question with some more details like; Does this happen all the time? When dragging local to local? Or is it only when dragging items to/from network locations?

Comment: I've seen this kind of behavior, but only with large files.  Does it happen with, say, an empty text document?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a rogue shell extension.

The first thing I would recommend is turning off your shell extensions, using [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Then turn them on one at a time.